# How do I create a database+tablespace+user in Oracle 11gR2?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, windows, configuration, tablespaces

Good evening,

I'm trying to figure out how to create a database+tablespace+user in Oracle 11g.

I've tried some tutorials, but nothing seems to work.

I cannot find Database Configuration Assistant either.

I'm running Windows 8 x64 with Oracle 11g R2, please tell me how I can do this task.

Thanks for all suggestions,

Alec Taylor

Comment: Can you specify which tutorials/methods/commands tried?

Answer (score 4):

I had no problems with a VirtualBox 4.14 Windows 8 preview VM and x64 Oracle 11gR2.
[image: Windows 8 Start Screen]
[image: Database Configuration Assistant]

My VM uses 40 GB Hard Disk. While installing it downloaded .Net Framework 3.51 
I started with a fresh Windows 8 VM in VirtualBox 4.14 and installed guest additions and run Windows update once. Afterwards I installed Oracle and got the items below on my Start page.

I find the databasefiles of my new database Bk_W8 in C:\app\berndk\oradata\Bk_W8. That is the location I would use for additional tablespaces.

The rest can be done by scripts which can be executed by sqlplus from this machine or from another client and is not Windows 8 specific.

**Edit:**

By right-clicking on the item on the start page, via advanced | open file location I found the path to the start menu:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Oracle - OraDb11g_home1\Konfigurations- und Migrations-Tools
```

I guess you will find

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

the other is specific for a German Oracle installation.

To get access to the hidden C:\ProgramData folder see [this link showing how to access folder options in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/345091/where-did-the-folder-option-dialog-go-in-windows-8-preview)

Final hint: My VM currently uses 23 GB for the virtual hard disk.

---

OK I'm going to retry this with the [Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2 (September 2011)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/downloads/index.html). But that takes some time.

Installation done:
The is the Web interface of Oracle 11g XE in Windows 8

[image]

For the question of creating addition databaseinstances: 
from [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705823/creating-new-database-under-oracle-xe-on-ubuntu) we learn, that it is not possible.

Creating tablespaces and users can be done using sqlplus. Which I found at C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\sqlplus.exe.

Now going to remove that Virtual machine. I think there are better ways to learn Oracle.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm running "Oracle Database 11g Express Edition", that it doesn't show up?

Comment: Yes, there is no DBCA with XE.

Comment: Yes XE has no Database Configuration Assistant. I have an x86 Version of XE running in XP. It uses some WEB interface for Configuration. Without trying I can't predict how your version behaves under Windows 8. The next few days I have no resources to check that.